# MySQL Max date query with a twist

Tags: mysql

I need to find the max date of a certification to set the archive field to 0. The twist part is that not all certifications have an expiration date. The existing update query is as follows:

```
update user_certs uc1
    join ( select user_id, cert_id, ifnull(max(date_expire),max(cert_date)) cert_date
        from user_certs
    group by user_id,cert_id ) uc2 on (uc1.user_id=uc2.user_id and uc1.cert_id=uc2.cert_id and ifnull(uc1.date_expire,uc1.cert_date)=uc2.cert_date)
    set uc1.archive=0
```

The query does not account for the multiple entries of the same cert in certain instances. One may have an expiration date, but the others may a more recent cert_date, but the expiration date is null because the record has not yet imported from the authoritative database.

The following query will account for that condition, but I cannot get it to work correctly. It keeps returning an invalid use of group function error even if I hard code the c.expiration value to 36 instead of joining.

```
update user_certs uc1
    join ( select user_id, cert_id, max(case when date_expire > cert_date + interval c.expiration month then date_expire else cert_date end ) cert_date
        from user_certs
        join certifications c on c.id = cert_id
    group by user_id,cert_id ) uc2 on (uc1.user_id=uc2.user_id and uc1.cert_id=uc2.cert_id and max(case when uc1.date_expire > uc1.cert_date + interval uc2.expiration month then uc1.date_expire else uc1.cert_date end )=uc2.cert_date)
    set uc1.archive = 0;
```

So I need to find the most recent certification based on either the greater of the expiration date or the cert_date + the certificate expiration (c.expiration) in months.

**UPDATE:**

Solved with the help of the comment from Jim MC. Corrected query is as follows:

```
update user_certs uc1
    join ( select user_id, cert_id, c.expiration, max(case when date_expire > cert_date + interval c.expiration month then date_expire else cert_date end ) cert_date
        from user_certs
        join certifications c on c.id = cert_id
    group by user_id,cert_id ) uc2 on (uc1.user_id=uc2.user_id and uc1.cert_id=uc2.cert_id and (case when uc1.date_expire > uc1.cert_date + interval uc2.expiration month then uc1.date_expire else uc1.cert_date end) = uc2.cert_date)
    set uc1.archive=0;
```

Comment: This isn't how I'd ask this question

Comment: Your syntax error is being caused by using MAX (the group function it's complaining about) in your ON clause.  MAX doesn't make sense there.

Comment: Thanks @JimMc! Got it figured out and posted the working query.